# Magento on click redirecting from menu item

Tags: magento

I am new to magento and infact am trying to learn from scratch. I have so far been able to add a menu item to the magento cms admin panel through my menu.xml file. Now what i want to do is onclick the menu item should redirect towards a view i am developing. I have added action to the add tag inside the xml page: 
`<add id="*******::SMS_configuration" title="SMS" module="******_SMS" sortOrder="99" parent="MbShastra_SMS::SMS" action="SMS/Controller/Index/Test" resource="*******_SMS::SMS_configuration"/>`
I know it's stupid but i was trying something.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure parent item 'MbShastra_SMS::SMS' is already defined or use any existing parent (for example content section parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements") 
Make sure routes are defined 
Action should be modulenamespace/controller name, in your case action='sms/index/test'

`<add id="*******::SMS_configuration" title="SMS" module="******_SMS" sortOrder="99" parent="MbShastra_SMS::SMS" action="sms/index/test" resource="*******_SMS::SMS_configuration"/>`

Comment: Where should i define the parent item 'MbShastra_SMS::SMS'? Also i have defined the route for my module but i type the route name directly as a url in the search box but have not been able to integrate that with the menu item. I guess i am confused how to do that.

Comment: Can you please answer my query. It will be a great help.